# Generate a list of random duration in minutes between 45 and 60, and add each random minute to a datetime column in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, datetime

I want to generate a random list of numbers between 45 and 60 which will represent the durations. Then I want to add each number in the list to the corresponding rows in a column in a pandas dataframe in datetime format.

This is the code I tried:

```
import random
import datetime 

min = [random.randint(45, 60) for x in range(45578)]
for i in min:
    duration = datetime.timedelta(minutes = i)
    filtered['checkout'] = filtered['checkin'] + duration

filtered.head()
```

The output of the code gives me a checkout column with just one particular duration added to the corresponding checkin column.
How do I modify the code to give me an addition of random values instead of a constant value, added to the corresponding checkin column?

Input and expected output:

```
               checkin             checkout
0  2023-07-30 07:00:00  2023-07-30 07:51:00
1  2023-07-30 08:00:00  2023-07-30 08:46:00
2  2023-07-30 09:00:00  2023-07-30 09:50:00
3  2023-07-30 10:00:00  2023-07-30 10:52:00
4  2023-07-30 11:00:00  2023-07-30 11:57:00
5  2023-07-30 12:00:00  2023-07-30 12:53:00
```

Comment: Could you please provide a reproducible example of your input and the matching expected output for clarity?

Comment: Don't use `min` as a name for a variable as it is a built-in function

Comment: @mozway Alright:

 
`min = [45. 45, 52, 48, 59, 55]`

`filtered = {'checkin': ['2023-07-30 07:00:00', '2023-07-30 08:00:00', '2023-07-30 9:00:00', '2023-07-30 10:00:00', '2023-07-30 11:00:00', '2023-07-30 12:00:00']} `


Expected output:


`filtered = {'checkout': ['2023-07-30 07:45:00', '2023-07-30 08:45:00', '2023-07-30 9:52:00', '2023-07-30 10:48:00', '2023-07-30 11:59:00', '2023-07-30 12:55:00']} `

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
# Sample DataFrame with a 'checkin' column
data = {'checkin': pd.to_datetime(['2023-09-08 08:00:00', '2023-09-08 09:30:00', '2023-09-08 10:45:00'])}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Generate a list of random durations between 45 and 60 minutes
random_durations = [random.randint(45, 60) for _ in range(len(df))]

# Add random durations to the 'checkin' column
df['checkout'] = df.apply(lambda row: row['checkin'] + datetime.timedelta(minutes=random.choice(random_durations)), axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can vectorize your code with:

```
# ensure datetime
filtered['checkin'] = pd.to_datetime(filtered['checkin'])

filtered['checkout'] = (filtered['checkin']
                      + pd.TimedeltaIndex(np.random.randint(45, 60, size=45578),
                                          unit='min')
                       )
```

Or, getting the needed length automatically:

```
filtered['checkin'] = pd.to_datetime(filtered['checkin'])
filtered['checkout'] = (filtered['checkin']
                      + pd.TimedeltaIndex(np.random.randint(45, 60,
                                                            size=len(filtered)),
                                          unit='min')
                       )
```

Output:

```
              checkin            checkout
0 2023-07-30 07:00:00 2023-07-30 07:56:00
1 2023-07-30 08:00:00 2023-07-30 08:53:00
2 2023-07-30 09:00:00 2023-07-30 09:48:00
3 2023-07-30 10:00:00 2023-07-30 10:55:00
4 2023-07-30 11:00:00 2023-07-30 11:55:00
5 2023-07-30 12:00:00 2023-07-30 12:54:00
```

#### Why did your approach fail?

at each step your overwriting the full column with a new (single) random timedelta, only the last occurrence matters

You could have used:

```
for i in filtered.index:
    duration = datetime.timedelta(minutes = random.randint(45, 60))
    filtered.loc[i, 'checkout'] = filtered.loc[i, 'checkin'] + duration
```

But a loop is inefficient.

Comment: @Splendor why did you unaccept?  Any issue with the answer?